# attempt to index global variable OE (a nil value) Lua with sql

Tags: sql, lua

```
mk = conn:query({live = true, sql = "SELECT DISTINCT OE.OderNumber,(SELECT R.ReportBody + ' CRLF ' +'Modified By: ' + UM.FirstName + ' at ' + UM.LastName + ' CRLF '+ 'Authored By: ' + UC.FirstName + ' at ' + UC.LastName + ' CRLF ' +'CRLF' AS [text()] FROM dbo.OrderReports R INNER JOIN dbo.Orders O ON R.OrderId = O.OrderId INNER JOIN dbo.Users UM ON R.ModifiedById = UM.UserId INNER JOIN dbo.Users UC ON R.CreatedById = UC.UserId WHERE O.OrderNumber = '"..OE.OderNumber.."' ORDER BY R.CreateDateFOR XML PATH('')) 'OrderReport' FROM dbo.vw_OrderLevelEvents OE"})
```

This query works just fine in SQL but while I have it with Lua, it says attempt to index global variable `OE`(a nil value)

How can i fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code :

```
WHERE O.OrderNumber = '"..OE.OderNumber.."' ORDER BY R.CreateDateFOR
```

Here you're using the `OderNumber` key of the `OE` table and its value is `nil`. You'll need to fix that before using its key.

EDIT : you really should rename it to `OrderNumber`, too! ;)